# touch in for loop

Tags: bash

`ls` gives me:

```
10 11 12 12L 13 16 702 702L
```

etc., and I'd like to create files

```
10_ 11_ 12_ 12L_ 13_
```

and so on. But,

```
$ for f in *; do touch "$f_"; done
```

gives me:

```
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
```

Also,

```
$ for f in *; do touch $f_; done
```

gives:

```
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
touch: missing file operand
```

I have over 100 files in this directory and haven't intention to do this without script.

Answer (score 7):

You *could* do it this way:

```
for f in *; do touch "${f}_"; done
```

[`man bash`/EXPANSION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion) says:

> The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with
>   more than one digit, or when parameter is **followed by a character
>   which is not to be interpreted as part of its name**.

However, this calls `touch` for every single file, which is quite inefficient. A better way is to let `printf` make a list of the files, zero-delimited in case of weird file names, and call `touch` only as often as needed with the help of `xargs`:

```
printf '%s_\0' * | xargs -0 touch
```